# Is there a way to vectorize this loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I wish to vectorize this for loop. This loop is about getting the coordinates of image pixels and form an array in a row by row order.

```
rows = 812; % 812x650 image
cols = 650;
n=rows*cols; % total number of pixels

index = zeros(n,2); % n coordinates of image pixels
pt_homo = zeros(3,1,n); % [x,y,1]'

k=1;
for r=1:rows
    for c=1:cols
        index(k,1)=c;
        index(k,2)=r;
        pt_homo(1,1,k) = c;
        pt_homo(2,1,k) = r;
        pt_homo(3,1,k) = 1;
        k=k+1;
    end
end
```

Comment: What is `n`, `rows`, `cols`. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My bad, I edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So if i understand your question correctly this should solve it

```
c = 1:cols;
r = 1:rows;
[X Y] = meshgrid(r,c);
index = [Y(:) X(:)];
pt_homo_ = permute([index ones(size(index,1),1)],[2 3 1]);
```

Basically what i did is create the index vectors and create a matrix of indexes using `meshgrid` and then reorder it to be in the format you wanted.